# Docker running inside vagrant + remote python debugging in Pycharm

Tags: debugging, docker, vagrant, pycharm

I'm running docker on top on vagrant and would like to debug application remotely using pycharm running on windows (which runs vagrant). Of course the docker host is then on vagrant - not the same machine pycharm is running on.

I have to specify the certificates folder and docker machine executable as a local files / directories. Does this mean I cannot debug applications using pycharm in this setup?

[image]

Of course I could ssh directly into the docker container but then I have no features pycharm gives me.

Answer (score 2):

#### pycharm cannot remote debug because cannot connect with code in docker in vagrant

you need bridge port from docker with vagrant before this.

1. you need find vagrant ip and docker ip (by default, vagrant ip: 10.0.2.2, you can see when run vagrant ssh)
2. second determine port for debug( exam 21000)
3. use commant code in terminal

   vagrant ssh

   sudo iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 21000 -j DNAT --to-destination 10.0.2.2:21000

   sudo iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -j MASQUERADE
4. set code for python file:
   change  172.19.0.1 with your docker ip (in vagrant)

   import pydevd
   pydevd.settrace('172.19.0.1', port=21000, suspend=False)
5. set on breakpoint on code and try to debug

Answer (score 1):

It is possible however not recommended, it has the potential to introduce a number of problem spots longer term and brings a increased security risk.

as per the docker documentation ...

[image]

If you are okay with the security risk and if docker toolbox using boot2docker is not an option for your situation, then you will need to ensure:

1. Docker client/server versions are **identical**
2. Port forwarding on your local vagrant box is setup
3. Add the TCP binding for the docker server, either as a replacement to the default unix socket binding and/or in addition.

[image]

Comment: I can connect to remote docker running on vagrant. The problem is that I cannot use docker-compose or any other feature PyCharm provides me with. I also cannot remote debug as I'm getting errors like "machine does not exist" - probably because docker wants me to point the certificates folder (and the machine itself?) within local directories and not the ones on vagrant. I believe up to some version there was a radio "docker-compose" instead of docker when adding remote interpreters. Why is it gone? How to point the docker-compose.yaml file?

Comment: I have not made use of the "Docker Compose" within windows pycharms. In looking at the docs, it appears to suggest that the feature is only available for linux/mac platforms. [prerequisites](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/2016.1/docker-compose.html)